# What is the difference between apachectl and httpd.worker?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, process

My hosting service, Webfaction, installs apache start scripts for django/python apps automatically. The installed start script is:

```
#!/bin/bash
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/mertnuhoglu/webapps/dj02/apache2/lib /home/mertnuhoglu/webapps/dj02/apache2/bin/httpd.worker -f /home/mertnuhoglu/webapps/dj02/apache2/conf/httpd.conf -k start
```

This script starts an **httpd.worker** instance:

```
 3364       00:03  8950 /home/mertnuhoglu/webapps/dj02/apache2/bin/httpd.worker
```

Recently, I followed [a tutorial](http://forum.webfaction.com/viewtopic.php?pid=13326) for custom app installation. In this tutorial, start script is defined as:

```
#!/bin/bash
/home/rocketmonkeys/webapps/django/apache2/bin/apachectl start
```

This script starts an **httpd -k start**:

```
 0.0  1620 17462 /home/mertnuhoglu/webapps/django/apache2/bin/httpd -k start
```

I would like to ask three things:

1. What is the difference between these two ways of starting apache server?
2. In the first script, which executable (`httpd.worker` or `httpd.conf` or something else) is run?
3. Why does `httpd` instance in the second example has `-k start` parameter? Is this due to `apachectl`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. `apachectl` is a wrapper over `httpd` and just sets some environment variables and adds further functionality, like `configtest`, more in detail [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/programs/apachectl.html). `httpd.worker` is like `httpd` but with the [worker module](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/worker.html) enabled.
2. The first script executes the `httpd.worker` binary with the `httpd.conf` configuration file.
3. Correct, `apachectl` appends the `-k start` parameter to `httpd`